# lightning-input checkbox margin-right

Tags: lightning-web-components, checkbox, slds-styling-hooks

I have a custom table in LWC and standard margin of

```
 <lightning-input 
                type="checkbox" 
                variant="label-hidden"
```

breaks cell center alignment.
I know that since it is a nested component I can't set css directly and I think it is also not possible to change via Styling Hooks?

[image: custom table]

Edit: just to simplify my question. lightning-input has a default margin-right and I need to get rid of it to center the checkbox in my td table cell correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last screenshot gives it away:

```css
margin-right: var(--lwc-spacingXSmall,0.5rem)
```

True, 0.5rem is the default. So set your own --lwc-spacingXSmall:

```css
:host {
    --lwc-spacingXSmall: 0;
}
```

It's all about the ["var" keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_css_custom_properties) here:

> A styling hook is a placeholder in the SLDS style sheet, for example, var(--slds-c-badge--color-background, #ecebea), which enables you to customize the style using the corresponding --slds-c-badge-color-background CSS custom property.

Maybe worth pointing out that the unfortunate "slds-checkbox_faux" seems the result of applying the "label-hidden" variant. I haven't checked, but you could play with other variants and leaving the label empty too.

Comment: works great, thank you!